# Linked Cells To Other Workbook Not Displaying Decimal Places

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two workbooks with several worksheets and I'm linking cells from one to the other using the following formula...

```
=IF(AND(E1>DAY(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())=1),0, '\\des.grplnk.net\home\My_Documents\TimeRecording\2020\[Timesheet.xlsm]Jan'!F3)
```

The cells in the workbook I'm linking to are formatted as numbers to 1 decimal place. However in the workbook I'm linking from the values are displayed to 0 decimal places. I've formatted the cells to 1 decimal place but it makes no difference.

I simply want the values displayed the same in the workbook I'm linking from as the one I'm linking to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The values what you are getting from other worksheet might have been treated as text. The below formula converts the returned Text to value.

```
=IF(AND(E1>DAY(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())=1),0, IFERROR(VALUE('\\des.grplnk.net\home\My_Documents\TimeRecording\2020\[Timesheet.xlsm]Jan'!F3),'\\des.grplnk.net\home\My_Documents\TimeRecording\2020\[Timesheet.xlsm]Jan'!F3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the formula, however the result is the same. Any further ideas?

Comment: Would you be able to add some screenshot references to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken some screenshots of the workbooks I'm linking from and to. The links are below as I can't embed images at the moment as I don't have enough rep.

[Workbook linking to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFmAs.png)

[Workbook linking from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8tf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have troubleshooting ideas, but not necessarily an outright solution:

- You might check the column width to ensure that it's displaying all
  of the decimal places.
- In the worksheet you're linking from, what happens when -- in another cell -- you add 0.1 to the linked cell? i.e.: is excel "seeing" the decimal places, just not displaying them?